# Optimize a South data migration for a huge number of objects

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

I'm working on a django project where I need a OneToOne relationship in the reverse direction. Previously, there was the `OneToOneField` `photo` in `MediaFile` pointing to the model `Photo`. I want to replace it with the new `OneToOneField` `mediafileobject` pointing back from `Photo` to `MediaFile`. (The reason is that the photo model will become unimportant in the future, and that we want an inline admin for the `Photo` model inside the `MediaFile` admin.)

When I run the data migration to copy the old relations to the new ones, after a minute there appears a

```
socket.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

The only plausible reason is that I operate on too many objects (about 20000). If only a few hundred objects are affected, the error will not appear. Here's the migration code I wrote:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    mediafiles = MediaFile.objects.all()
    for mediafile in mediafiles:
        try:
            mediafile.photo.mediafileobject = mediafile
        except AttributeError:
            pass # When mediafile.photo is None
        else:
            mediafile.photo.save()
```

How can I optimize this? I'm working with django1.3, South0.7.3, and MySQL. The schema migration is done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use django's [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#module-django.core.paginator) to split the queryset into pages/chunks:

```
paginator = Paginator(MediaFile.objects.all(), 10)
for i in xrange(1, paginator.num_pages):
    for mediafile in paginator.page(i).object_list:
        try:
            mediafile.photo.mediafileobject = mediafile
        except AttributeError:
            pass # When mediafile.photo is None
        else:
            mediafile.photo.save()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your code didn't solve my problem directly, but produced a different error message that helped me to find the origin of the error: Things in the save method of the Photo class. Bypassing `save()` by using `update()` finally solved the problem.